# Error on compiling a libmicrohttpd program. (MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT)

Tags: c++, g++

I've looked all over the internet for this issue and doesnt appear to be a recurrent error.

The problem comes when I try to compile (I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 distro) with g++ the main file that includes the  lib, and it gets all the variables and functions except the MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT variable on:

`response = MHD_create_response_from_buffer(strlen(page), (void*)page, MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);`

I already checked the linkers and everything to compile with -lmicrohttpd. 
My Makefile looks like this:

```
CC = g++ -std=c++11
INCLUDE = -I. -I/opt/local/include 
CFLAGS = -g -Wall $(INCLUDE)
#CFLAGS = -g -Wall $(INCLUDE) -coverage
LDFLAGS = -L/opt/local/lib -lmicrohttpd 

all: $(TARGET)

$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.cc
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

I didnt attach the linker fot $Objects, but its ok.
Actually, its very weird problem, because when i installed the packages (libmicrohttpd-dev and libmicrohttpd-dbg) on other PC's it worked out ok, but in some cases this issue comes up. The only solution that I came with was to re-install the OS again and start over, because everything was unefective.

It worked before on this very same computer, with the same OS, but since i had to format it, i have no idea to correct this issue.

Any ideas?.

Comment: Are you sure that the version of libmicrohttpd-dev installed isn't too old ?

Comment: Actually i cant get any newer version using apt-get command. Aparentely i'm using a 0.4.6-1 version.
Porbably that could be the reason. Do you know how to do an upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT as been added in libmicrohttpd 0.9.x, so version 0.4.6-1 is too old.

With Ubuntu, I don't know exactly how you can upgrade, but as libmicrohttpd as very few dependencies, maybe just add another ubuntu repo, or download a .deb and install it manually with dependencies.
Or apt-get remove the installed one, and manually install the latest version from [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/)

Comment: Yes. I figure it out now about the release date.
The problem now is to upgrade that package. I've downloaded the right package, but the system doesnt let me install it.